# Using logger in Nodewebkit environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, hapi.js

We have one code base (React.js and Hapi.js). Based on that code base, we have two versions of the application.
One is just a normal Web application, the other one is a Nodewebkit(Desktop) version:

- nw.js v0.12.3
- io.js v1.2.0
- Chromium 41.0.2272.76

Essentially applications are the same, with slight differences. For example, web version has a user (log in) management, while the desktop does not have. Web verison uses MySQL, while the desktop version uses Sqlite. There are more differences, but it is not relevant to the question :)

The issue we face is a how to make a proper logger for Nodewebkit version. In the web version we have implemented Good-console for the Hapi.js. It goes something like this:

```
var options = {
ops: {
    interval: 1000
},
reporters: config.loggers
};

models.sequelize.sync(/*{force: true}*/).then(function(){
server.register({
register: require('good'),
options: options
 }, (err) =>{

if(err) {
  console.error(err);
} else {
  server.start(() =>{
    console.info('Server started at ' + server.info.uri);
  });
}
});
```

And later in the code it is used as:

```
}).catch(function (err) {
            request.server.log(['error'], err.stack);
            response({isError: true, message: 'Could not retrieve connection  information'}).code(200);
        });
```

That works just as expected.

Issue we face is how to include the same logging facility in the Nodewebkit environment.
Normally, since we use the same code base, log calls should be also the same. All files in the application are the same, except the index.js. We have two versions, one to start the NW.js and another one for normal web startup.

If we use the Good-console initialization code (that works in web verison) in the NW.js startup file, nothing happens. Server is not started, and there is no error.
I have transpiled the node-modules used by good console to ECMA5, since NW.js engine is not running ECMA6, but again nothing happens.

Earlier, we have though implemented a simple logger for NW.js version. Which was used only during the startup and it goes something like this:

```
log4js = require('log4js');
log4js.configure({
appenders: [
    { type: 'console' },
    { type: 'file', filename: 'logs/project.log', category: 'projects' }        
    ]
});

logger = log4js.getLogger('projects');
logger.setLevel('ERROR');
logger.setLevel('INFO');

server.route(require('./server/config/routes'));
models.sequelize.sync({/*force: true*/}).then(function () {
server.start(function () {
    logger.info('Nodeweb kit Fun is Started :).');
});
 });
```

Trick is how to use the same logger calls, without infesintg the code with 'if' or similar tricks in the code. To clarify the issue:

Good console code:

```
 request.server.log(['error'], err.stack);
 request.server.log(['error'], err.stack);
```

log4js code:

```
logger.info('Nodeweb kit Fun is Started :).');
```

Is there a possibility to attach (when the NW version is started) log4js functions to a request.server, so the code is not aware of the loggin facility?

Or some other idea is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to use the same code for logging in both versions.
Simply in NW version I have installed [hapi-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-logger) plugin.

Both plugins use the same function signature now:

```
request.server.log(['error'], err.stack);
```